# Solving for a general solution in $y' = y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

My book gives me $y' = y^2$ and then asks me to find the general solution.

I am getting $\displaystyle\frac{-1}{(c+x)}$ as my answer.

However, both the book's answer key AND Wolfram report to me that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{(c-x)}$ is the answer which I am NOT getting.

Comment: Both are the same, $\dfrac{-1}{c+x} = \dfrac{1}{-(c+x)} = \dfrac{1}{(-c)-x}$.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Joe clarified it that the '-' is made 'null'. Unless I understood that incorrectly.

Comment: Well, $c$ is an arbitrary constant. The only difference is what value $c$ gets in both forms to obtain the same function. Where you would choose $c = 1$, the book and Wolfram would choose $c = -1$. Where they would choose $c = 12$, you'd choose $c = -12$.

Comment: By the way, this is not quite the general solution. There is also $y=0$, which is not included in the answer given.

Comment: Would you say that on a given test, my answer should be correct as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the answers are equivalent. Generally we assume $c$ to be a positive number, just so we have less negative terms to deal with. Note that $-c \equiv c$ since we just consider $c$ to be some constant (it could be negative or positive). Based on this, one can simply multiply through by $-1$ to obtain the answer that Wolfram got.

Comment: Woww, so I am getting the right answer? I just never knew that "c" could be negative in the first place?

Comment: Joe, you type too fast :) +1

Comment: Yeah, you're correct. Think of c similar to the "+c" you get when doing indefinite integrals. You get a family of functions that is the primitive of your given function $F(x)$. This family of functions may include some that have a positive number for $c$ and some that have a negative number. Consider that when you take the derivative of your result from integrating, the $+c$ term disappears since the derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: Great, thank you! I have been on this for an hour, and never learned (or missed) that the -c just becomes c.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your answer and the Wolfram answer occurs because you can choose to multiply by $-1$ at any point. Note that $\int y^{-2}y'dx = \int y^{-2}dy$ so we have $$\int y^{-2}dy = \int 1 dx.$$ As $\frac{d}{dy}(y^{-1}) = -y^{-2}$, we see that $y^{-1}$ is an antiderivative for $-y^{-2}$. Multiplying the previous equation by $-1$ we have

\begin{align*}
\int -y^{-2} dy =& \int -1 dx\\
y^{-1} &= -x + c_1
\end{align*}

so $y = \frac{1}{c_1 - x}$. Alternatively, from $\frac{d}{dy}(y^{-1}) = -y^{-2}$ we can multiply by $-1$ to obtain $\frac{d}{dy}(-y^{-1}) = y^{-2}$; that is, $-y^{-1}$ is an antiderivative for $y^{-2}$. Therefore we have

\begin{align*}
\int y^{-2} dy &= \int 1 dx\\
-y^{-1} &= x + c_2
\end{align*}

so $y = \frac{-1}{c_2 + x}$. This is why you get seemingly different answers. Note, as Daniel Fischer pointed out, the arbitrary constants in the two expressions are not the same, i.e. $c_1 \neq c_2$. In fact, $c_2 = - c_1$.

Comment: I am just starting to teach myself differential equations. Your Method is Separation of variables, yeah?

Comment: Yes, if by separation of variables you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_.28ODE.29).

Comment: Is there a way to solve for the genera solution without? Just wondering, because the section tries to ask you to solve, and seperation is taught 3 sections later.

Comment: How did you do it?

Comment: I used seperation like you did, but the book teaches it after this problem. So I'm just wondering if there is another way. (We had all 3 lectures in the same day)

Comment: @JonWei The textbook may have expected you to be able to 'guess' the solution based on inspection. After thinking for a minute or two, I don't really see an easy way to solve this DE without using separation or methods you would learn later in the course. Usually separation of variables is the first method you learn for solving ODEs.